# What is meant by conservation of momentum?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, momentum, conservation-laws

I need proof of this. Some examples are also required.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows no research effort.

Comment: It might be that the question is just poorly formulated. At least I would like to think so.

Comment: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/242497/why-is-this-specific-definition-of-acceleration-used-in-deriving-a-general-equat/242527#242527

Answer (score 1):

Of course a good answer to this question is a reference to the book.
Shortly one can say that conservation of momentum is a consequence of the homogeneity of space. How exactly is well describe on a single page #15 in the Landau Lifshitz book which you can download [here](https://archive.org/details/Mechanics_541).

I suggest first to read the the related chapter, so you will grasp the idea and then read the first 15 pages, so that you will really grasp all the concepts introduced.

P.S. If the explanation seems to complicated for you, please provide your background so one can suggest appropriate source.